# What data structure is used to store HDFS Metadata?

Tags: data-structures, hdfs

I faced this question in a technical interview and had no idea about it.
Metadata in Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) represents the relationship between blocks and file or directories they associated with. Metadata also includes some other information such as sequence in the file, ACLs and checksum ... 
What data structure is used to store the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS holds file metadata including type (regular file, or directory), and the list of blocks that are pointers to the data in form of **inode** which is like Linux systems.

[image]

Picture uploaded by [Bikash Agrawal](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315678657_Scalable_Data_Processing_and_Analytical_Approach_for_Big_Data_Cloud_Platform) which shows Structure of ext4 inode which stores HDFS data blocks.